# Redirecting contents not using HTTP

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to have apache respond to server request of the format "http://url.com/dir/ID" by directly accessing "http://url.com/something:PORT", where the ID is set by the user, and the PORT is determined by the ID (they're not the same value).

I have tried so with "Redirect", but this simply sends a HTTP redirect, my goal to to directly feed the contains of "http://url.com/something:PORT" to "http://url.com/dir/ID".

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
Example:
The requester goes to `http://url.com/dir/ID` and does not get redirected to `http://url.com/something:PORT` but gets the actual contents of `http://url.com/something:PORT`as if the original request was to here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing mod_rewrite and putting the following in your .htaccess or httpd.conf :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /something/
RewriteRule ^(url.com/dir/*)$ http://url.com:$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is a 301 'permanent' redirect which would also change linked URLs in search engines to your final address. More information [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

You may need to change the Regex to fit your situation, I'm not 100% sure what result you are looking for. If you can provide a few examples of a specific URL the user will access and the specific URL you would like them to be sent to I may be able to help you more.

Comment: This will send the HTTP reply of 301. The problem is, that the receiver does not understand this reply, and so it will not follow the redirect url. I want Apache to return whatever is at "something:PORT" when requested for "dir/ID".

Comment: Still not sure what you mean, can you update your question with some specific examples of the request/target URL? What is the receiver in this instance?

Comment: I have elaborated a bit in my post. My receiver is an SCM.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?dir/ID$ /something:PORT [L]
```

If you're referring to resourcing actually sitting on another server at `something:PORT`, you need to send the request over to mod_proxy so that it can reverse proxy for you. If you don't have mod_proxy turned on, then there's not much you can do, perhaps find some php proxying solution.

In htaccess, you can invoke mod_proxy by using the `P` flag, for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?dir/ID$ http://something:PORT/ [L,P]
```